# Separation of Concerns - .Net Code Identity + Duende.IdentityServer good practice recommendation

Tags: .net-core, domain-driven-design, asp.net-core-identity, duende-identity-server

Its ok if I call some services of the domain after a user registers?
I'm having some trouble when trying not to add the dependency to .net Core Identity into my domain model.

However I'm thinking I can make the actions I need for my domain app by adding some code in between the .net Core Identity code.

I'm looking for best practices recommendations for this!

Thanks in advance!